# How we can send reminders push notification when shored date matched with current date.

Tags: php, push-notification, drupal-7

Send Push notification to invited users when event date matched with the current date. Please let me know if any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use cronjob : 
https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron && 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7.x &&
https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/cron_example%21cron_example.module/7.x-1.x

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the cron job for the same. 
Follow this steps.
1. Find all events with current date
2. Find invited users for those events
3. send notification to those users.

P.s if you want to send push notification on web you need to use socket with PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom module and add a hook_cron(). Please use following Steps:

1. Create a function where you get the list of all email id where you need to send mail for event notification.

1.a : Add a page/template, where you can create mail body and subject. which data send to user.

1.b : Add a function for send mail on mail ID.

1. Call the mail (above function which you have created for send mail) function inside you cron job.
2. Install [Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) and set time for you cron which you have created in custom module,

   please let me know if you need any more details.